# ExpressMapper Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, express-mapper

I'm using ExpressMapper/C# to map/copy one object to a similar object (but of a different type)

I get the error 'Value cannot be null'.

The object I'm mapping isn't null, so I assume there's an issue with one of the object properties.

The problem is I have a large number of properties and I can't pinpoint the specific one that has an issue, and the error message doesn't give any further info (e.g The name of the Property/Variable that's null)

How can I find out more info about what's causing the issue?

Comment: Please post your code/exact process you went through to generate the error

Comment: If you have a large number of properties then use the process of divide an conquer to work it out. If you had 1,000,000 properties it would only take 20 steps of cutting them in half to find one specific property.